# Spot the problem in the contract of the unsellable token

Tags: solidity, erc-20, contract-debugging, scam

I am currently trying to understand how the smart contracts work. I have bought a tiny amount of a token that I suspect to be honeypot and indeed it is unsellable, PancakeSwap gives the error: Transaction reverted, try to increase the slippage tolerance (increasing the tolerance actually doesn't work). However, from the transactions list I do see that the owner is able to sell the token.

This is bscscan link for the contract. The buyback limits look OK also I can't see in the code a condition that allows selling only for the owner. Could you spot the problem in the contract?

https://bscscan.com/address/0xe2b59378773e4660c77e7104e9a15cbb79e9ffff#code